# Convert two svn repostories to git

Tags: git, svn

Is there a simple way to convert 2 svn repositories into one git repository without loosing commit history?
I found few examples how to convert svn repository into git, but I have no luck how to do this with two repositories

Comment: how are these two repos related / how are they supposed to be combined?

Comment: response from @honk is enough for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward solution would be to import both SVN repositories into their own git repositories and then combine these two into a single one with `git subtree` (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories) or any documentation on git).